# Where can I use wildcards %1 and $1?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've digging around Apache syntax, but I don't understand where can I use the `$1` and `%1` wildcards. I have the next code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !PHPSESSID=(.*);.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.*/usuarios/%1/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*/usuarios/
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|wbmp)$ - [R=404,L]
```

It means:

1. If user doesn't have session_id associated or he's not accessing to `/.../usuarios/session_id/...`.
2. And user is accessing to `/.../usuarios/...
3. Then, redirect to 404 response.

The first part is not working right. Can I use `%1` like above? Can I use it in the first part of `RewriteRule`?

If not, how can I implement that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `%1` - Capture from `RewriteCond` and use it in RHS of `RewriteRule`
- `$1` - Capture from `RewriteRule` and use it in LHS of `RewriteCond` OR RHS of `RewriteRule`

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

PS: Your condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.*/usuarios/%1/.*$` is not going to work since you cannot use `%1` in RHS of `RewriteCond`

**UPDATE:** You can try something like this to use **back-reference variables**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !PHPSESSID=(.+) [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}:%{REQUEST_URI} ^PHPSESSID=(.*?);:(?!.*?/usuarios/\1).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*?/usuarios/.+?\.(gif|jpe?g|png|wbmp)$ - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: Thanks again. So how could I use the `session_id` in `RewriteCond`?

Comment: I haven't forgotten about it, tab is still open. Just got busy in some project related issues. Will definitely update it this evening.

Comment: Thanks, but this sentence: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}:%{REQUEST_URI} !^PHPSESSID=(.*?);:/usuarios/\1/` doesn't work.

Comment: What does the colon do? Is it like an `AND` expression?

Comment: colon `:` is actually just a literal delimiter which is being used both on LHS and RHS. If you tell me which URL you tried to test it, I will try reproducing same behavior in my local env and post the improved answer here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40373/discussion-between-manolo-salsas-and-anubhava)

Comment: Well, I leaved a message if you to see.

Comment: Very tricky problem to solve but I'm glad we found a workable solution.